# Rollup js to stop importing the built in node modules

Tags: node.js, bundler, rollup, rollupjs

I am using rollup to bundle my component. Somewhere I think it has TextEncoder as peer dependency. While bundling with rollup, it adds import statement `import {TextEncoder} from "util"` , followed by `new TextEncoder()`.

I am getting error TextEncoder is not a constructor. If I remove the import statement then the error does not appear since it uses the build in browser's TextEncoder class. How can I bundle the component with using textencoder from window instead of util. So, basically if I am able to remove the import statement, it resolves the problem